# Using nopcommerce 4.10 , How to exclude some products from category discount?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I am using Nopcommerce 4.10 , one feature in nopcommerce is that I can apply discount to category.
Myquestion is how to exclude some products from this category discount?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, set the Discount type to Assigned to products.

When you have set the information in the Discount Info tab, press Save and Continue Edit. You can click now on the tab Applied to products.

When you have done that press on the button Add a new product. Then you can search for products that have a certain category. When you have searched on the category.

You can select the checkbox in front of the products you want to add to the discount that you just have created. Then press Save.

Comment: i dont want to assign discount to product one by one , i want to assign discount to all category products but exclude one from them

Comment: @HodaOsama so far that I know of, there is no option that does what you want. Then you need to build it yourself.

With the steps above you can select 100 products at the same time(with one click).I know it is not ideal but it is an option.

Comment: You need to use Discount requirement, but is not available out of the box. You need to implement a new rule that exlude your product.